# An image_path is showing up along with image uploaded

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, image, carrierwave, actionview

while I upload the image the image a paragraph of unwanted text is showing up below the image.
[here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ETqV.png)
the view file has the following code:

```
<li id="project-<%= project.id %>">
  <%= link_to gravatar_for(project.user, size: 50), project.user %>
  <span class="user"><%= link_to project.user.name, project.user %></span>
  <span class="content">
    <%= project.title %>
    <%= project.content %>
    <%= project.pictures.each do |p| %>
    <%= image_tag p.url %>
    <% end %>
  </span>
  <span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(project.created_at) %> ago.
    <% if current_user?(project.user) %>
    <%= link_to "delete", project, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?"} %>
    <%= link_to "edit", "/projects/#{project.id}/edit", method: :get %>
    <% end %>
  </span>
</li>
```

Any suggestion or help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is here `<%= project.pictures.each do |p| %>`.

Change it to:

```
<% project.pictures.each do |p| %>
```